# Building a interactive application that accepts lists of arbitrary length as inputs

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I have the following function (Class Shape Transformation):

```
cst[wl, wu, dz]
```

where `wl` and `wu` are lists of undefined length:

```
wl = {wl1, wl2, wl3, ... }

wu = {wu1, wu2, wu3, ... }
```

and the elements of these lists are all real numbers varying from 0 to 1; and `dz` is another real number.

```
n = 100;
n1 = 0.5; n2 = 1;
z = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
x = ConstantArray[1, n + 1];
For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++; 
  z[[i]] = 2 Pi / n (i - 1); 
  x[[i]] = 0.5 (Cos[z[[i]]] + 1 )];
ind0 = Position[x, 0. ]; 
a = ind0[[1]] - 1; 
xl = Take[x, a[[1]]]; 
xu = Flatten[List[0, Take[x, -a[[1]]]]];
class[x_] := x^n1 (1 - x)^n2;
nw[w_] := Length[w] - 1;
shape[w_, x_] := Sum[BernsteinBasis[nw[w], j - 1, x] w[[j]], {j, nw[w] + 1}];
y[w_, x_, dz_] := class[x] shape[w, x] + x dz;
cst[wl_, wu_, dz_] := Transpose[{x, Flatten[{y[wl, xl, -dz], y[wu, xu, dz]}]}];
```

I would like to manipulate `wl` and `wu` elements with a 0 to 1 range, specifying their lengths together with `dz` with a menu. I tried something like this, but it didn't work out:

```
Manipulate[
  ListPlot[cst[wl, wu, dz]], 
  {{wu[[1]], 0, 0.1, 1}, ...}, 
  {{wl[[1]], 0, 0.1, 1}, ...}, 
  {nu, Length[wl]}, 
  {nl, Length[wu]}, 
  {dz}, ControlType -> {PopupMenu}]
```

This is an example of how cst fuctio works, as suggested by Goldberg.

```
dz = 0.0002;
wu = {0.19, 0.20, 0.29, 0.27, 0.31, 0.16};
wl = {-0.12, -0.13, -0.14, -0.16, -0.15, 0.1};
```

The output with a plot would be:

```
ListPlot[cst[wl, wu, dz]]
```

[image]

Comment: ...I don't see a definition for `cst` anywhere.

Comment: I've just added the definition, thank you. If anyone is interested it's a code for Brenda Kulfan's Class Shape Transformation (CST).

Comment: The first thing you should do is get the code you wrote to provide the constructs to be manipulated working. What you show in your post does not work and must be fixed before it is reasonable to attempt interacting with it. For instance, `x` and `z` have fixed lengths `n + 1`, so `n` must be specified, but you don't do that. You give `For` three arguments, but it requires four. Until you correct these simple errors, I don't think there is much we do to help you build your interactive code.

Comment: I beg your pardon, you're right. I forgot to insert n. The rest should work. You may verify, plotting:
ListPlot[cst[wl, wu, dz]]

Comment: Your code won't work when `n` is an odd number. But you don't say anything about the parity of `n`. Do you have a policy for handling odd `n`?

Comment: Please give an example of a call to `cst` and that gives a result you know to be correct and that we can use when working with your code. I'm asking for this because I am having trouble finding any set of arguments that I can give to `cst` that doesn't produce an error.

Comment: Yes. Will add quickly.

Comment: Yes @m_goldberg the code works only with n not being an odd umber. It has to be even because half of the points must be on the upper surface and the other half in the lower. Thaks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I now believe I understand what you trying to accomplish. You want to be able to manipulate the shape of an airfoil, right? I have some ideas. If you hang in for a little while, I will be back a proposal on how a `Manipulate` might work. Meanwhile, I will post an interim answer that will let look at shape variations fairly easily without using `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that will let you vary the shape you are rendering fairly easily but does not use `Manipulate`. It might be useful to you in the short term. I will put more work in this problem, and try to build a useful interactive version with `Manipulate`. I will update this answer when I have such code.

```
With[{n = 100},
  z = Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, n];
  x = .5 (1 + Cos[#]) & /@ z;
  {xl, xu} = TakeDrop[x, n/2];]

With[{n1 = .5, n2 = 1.}, class[x_] := x^n1 (1 - x)^n2]

shape[w_, x_] := 
  With[{n = Length[w]}, Sum[BernsteinBasis[n - 1, j - 1, x] w[[j]], {j, n}]]
y[w_, x_, dz_] := class[x] shape[w, x] + x dz
cst[wl_, wu_, dz_] := Transpose[{x, Flatten[{y[wl, xl, -dz], y[wu, xu, dz]}]}]
```

Note that the above code simplifies and speeds up the computation of `x`, `xu` and `xl`.

I recommend expressing the plot within a `With` expression that assigns the parameters.

```
With[
  {dz = 0.0002,
   wup = {.19, .20, .29, .27, .31, .16},
   wlo = {-.12, -.13, -.14, -.16, -.15, .1}},
  ListPlot[cst[wlo, wup, dz]]]
```

[image: plot-1]

Using `With` makes it easy to specify a new design by simply editing the parameter definitions. For example,

```
With[
  {dz = 0.0005,
   wup = {.19, .21, .29, .27, .3, .2, .1},
   wlo = {-.12, -.13, -.14, -.16, -.15, -.2, -.1}},
  ListPlot[cst[wlo, wup, dz]]]
```

[image: plot-2]

This is not too bad a way to explore the design space, even if it is not as sexy as interactive manipulation.

#### Update

Here is an interactive version. It's pretty simple but I think it is usable. I decided that inputs fields would be an easy and simple way to get the user's inputs. Input fields are something everyone can be expected to understand, but have the disadvantage of being hard to make bullet-proof. I implemented only a minimum of input checking — just enough to give a hint of how it might done. I think implementing elaborate input checking is out of scope for this question. I leave it as an exercise to the reader.

I only show the new code. Everything else is as it was before.

```
test = List[RepeatedNull[_Real?(Between[#, {-1., 1.}] &)]];
badParamMsg = 
  "one of the inputs, w-upper, w-lower or dz, is invalid";
okMsg = Invisible[
   "one of the inputs, w-upper, w-lower or dz, is invalid"];

Manipulate[
  If[MatchQ[wlo, test] && MatchQ[wup, test] && MatchQ[dz, _Real],
    pts = cst[wlo, wup, dz]; msg = okMsg,
    pts = {}; msg = badParamMsg];
  Column[
    {ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}],
     Style[Row[{"Message  ", Framed[msg]}], "SR", 11]},
    Center],
  {{wup, {.19, .21, .29, .27, .3, .2, .1}, "w-upper"},
    InputField, ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}}, 
  {{wlo, {-.12, -.13, -.14, -.16, -.15, -.2, -.1}, "w-lower"}, 
    InputField, ImageSize -> {500, Automatic}},
  {{dz, .0002, "dz"}, InputField, ImageSize -> {50, Automatic}},
  {{pts, {}}, None},
  {{msg, okMsg}, None},
  TrackedSymbols :> {wlo, wup, dz},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: interactive]

To get a edit to an input field recognized, you must <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the field. Do not press <kbd>Return</kbd> — that will result in a new `Manipulate` panel being generated.

Comment: There is still an issue here. The lengths of the wup and wlow don't necessarily have to be the same. The only restriction given is to the parameter n (needs to be an even number), yet we have considered it constant.

Comment: Indeed, the length of these vectors assign the complexity of the polynomials and therefore of the shape of the upper and lower lines of the airfoil. It may be possible that  such complexity may differ between upper and lower lines. Often lower lines are more complex than upper.

Comment: I've made your code plot the airfoil even under this condition.

Comment: @MirkoAveta. My bad. I was only trying show how simple input validation might work. I have corrected the `Manipulate` code to use a somewhat more complex, but more useful, test. It now permits `wlo` and `wup` to vary independently, as you see from the new image.