# Problems with NMaximize

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

The Objective function I would like to Maximize takes less than a second to evaluate. There are several packages needed to evaluate it, so I'm not showing it here.

```
Timing[fitcst[{-0.3, -0.2}, {0.2, 0.1}, sol]]
```

Returns correctly,

```
{0.284273, 0.000898708}
```

I was wondering why using NMaximize I never get a single result (I tried setting the time limit to 10000):

t=10000;

```
 TimeConstrained[
     NMaximize[ {fitcst[{wl1, wl2}, {wu1, wu2}, sol], -1 < wl1 < 0, -1 < 
        wl2 < 0, 0 < wu1 < 1, 
       0 < wu2 < 1}, {{wl1, -0.7, -0.5}, {wl2, -0.5, -0.4}, {wu1, 0.5, 
        0.6}, {wu2, 0.2, 0.3}}, 
      Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "CrossProbability" -> 0.5, 
        "SearchPoints" -> 1 }, AccuracyGoal -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 2, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 1, 
      StepMonitor :> Print["Step to x = ", {wl1, wl2,  wu1, wu2}]], t]
```

Am I wrongly setting something?

**UPDATE**

I tried evaluating the following.

```
    bubu[wl1_, wl2_, wu1_, wu2_] := 
 With[{a = 0}, wl1^10 + wl2^20 + wu1^20 + wu2^20 + a]

TimeConstrained[
 NMinimize[{bubu[wl1, wl2, wu1, wu2], -1 < wl1 < 0, -1 < wl2 < 0, 
   0 < wu1 < 1, 
   0 < wu2 < 1}, {{wl1, -0.4, -0.3}, {wl2, -0.4, -0.3}, {wu1, 0.4, 
    0.5}, {wu2, 0.3, 0.4}} , 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "CrossProbability" -> 0.5, 
    "SearchPoints" -> 2 }, AccuracyGoal -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 1, 
  StepMonitor :> Print["Step to x = ", {wl1, wl2,  wu1, wu2}]], 20]
```

And it works. So I have effectively setted correctly NMaximize.

Have you any suggestions? What might be the problem??

**UPDATE 2**

I've added a command inside my function that would save its partial results to see what it is doing. I have found that the partial results contained the design space variables as symbols instead of assigning numbers. This might explain why it isn't working.

**UPDATE 3**

Oleksandr suggested to add _?NumericQ to my variables. It still doesn't work, giving me an error msg. Also, if I try evaluating my function now it doesn't evaluate results anymore. This is how I defined my function:

```
 fitcst[wlo_?NumericQ, wup_?NumericQ, sol_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{m = 50, \[Alpha] = 2 Degree},
  pts = cst[wlo, wup];
(...)
]
```

**UPDATE 4**

As pointed out, the first two variables are vectors so this wasn't the proper way to use NumericQ. Using the following it now evaluates but NMaximize still won't work.

```
fitcst[wlo_?NumericQ, wup_?NumericQ, sol_?NumericQ] := 
     With[{m = 50, \[Alpha] = 2 Degree},
      pts = cst[wlo, wup];
    (...)
    ]
```

Indeed this is my output.

```
NMaximize::nnum: "The function value {-0.534412} is not a number at {wl1,wl2,wu1,wu2} = {-0.32,-0.31,0.45497152228804144113993856990418862551`2.,0.396484375`}"
```

Why does it say it isn't a number??

Comment: What is fitcst?

Comment: Its my function. I can't post it here because it needs several packages to evaluate. Anyhow It perfectly works.

Comment: What does your `fitcst` function do with symbolic input?

Comment: It reads Class Shape Transforation design variables for airfoil generation [link]( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113222/building-a-interactive-application-that-accepts-lists-of-arbitrary-length-as-inp), evaluates the lift coefficient and verifies a geometrical condition, finally it returns a fitness function through goal programming

Comment: Your differential evolution parameters are grossly inappropriate, so it is not surprising that it doesn't work. You would need at least 20 search points, not 1 or 2. And your crossover probability should be close to 0 or 1, not 0.5.

Comment: Ok, I'll try as you suggest.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I also tried using other type of methods but it simply won't evaluate. I believe that there must be some kind of problem when NMaximize assigns a value to my function.

Comment: You may try adding `?NumericQ` guards on the parameters of your function. Without a concrete example that reproduces the problem, I think we will just be guessing at possible solutions. However, please note that what I said above is true independently of whether it resolves this particular issue or not.

Comment: Ok. I've done something to prove my suspects. I added a command that would save what Mathematica is doing at every evaluation. It saved, instead of properly evaluated functions, the functions evaluating symbols!! Why is it doing so?

Comment: Please search on this site about `NumericQ`; a list of some relevant questions/answers is given [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037). I believe that this is such a common question that there is little point in reiterating everything here. If it doesn't solve your problem (and, consider that you may have to restart *Mathematica* to clear out old definitions), please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I've just updated my question.

Comment: A 2-vector is not a numeric quantity. Your definition should have had e.g. `fitcst[wlo : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, wup : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ},
   sol_?NumericQ] := ...` (I assume `sol` is a numeric quantity, but you don't say how it is defined, so this may not be the case.)

Comment: Indeed wlo and wup are vectors. Ok I'll try this! Thanks again

Comment: I updated again. It still outputs a funny error.

Comment: {-0.534412} is not a number, it's a list. Your function appears to be returning a list instead of a number at the given values of the parameters.

Comment: You are apparently returning your result inside a list for some reason. You can get the same error with `NMaximize[{{-x^2}}, x]`. Remove this unnecessary list head and it will most likely work. By the way, this entire process of trial and error could have been avoided if you had provided a minimal working example that reproduces your problem rather than stating only what doesn't work. In fact, questions that do not provide a MWE are often closed as unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out kindly by Oleksandr I bumped into a common beginner's error. Reference to this can be found in the following links:
[HERE](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502)
[and HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)
The correct way to do this, in my case, as I have vectors as variables would have been:

```
    fitcst[wlo : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, wup : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ},
  sol_] := With[{m = 50, \[Alpha] = 2 Degree},
  pts = cst[wlo, wup];
(...)
]
```

Important suggestions on how to use the "Differential Evolution" method can be found in the comments.